# Issue installing Opencv-python on windows x64 bit

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I have installed OpenCV for python 3.8.5 - 32 bit and it worked perfectly fine. I decided to use the 64bit version of python, as my PC's system type is x64-based, but OpenCV-python does not install properly. This is the error I receive when trying to import cv2.

Command used to install Opencv -> 'pip install opencv-contrib-python'

[error while testing opencv install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfK9m.png)

Comment: does pip install opencv-python work ? At least just to check.

Comment: yes the command works. It says that the installation was successful but when trying to import cv2 it does not work.

Comment: There has recently been an issue with numpy 1.19.4 on Window 64-bit. Opencv requires 1.19.3 or over, but unless you specifically install 1.19.3 first, it will retrieve 1.19.4 (or use a cached version of it). Try manually installing 1.19.3 with `pip install numpy==1.19.3` in a fresh environment and then installing opencv into the same environment.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Installing the previous version on numpy before installing the OpenCV package worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can make virtual environment and then install python3.8 64-bit there,and then you can install opencv-contrib for this version,

download and install virtualenv and make an virtualenv:

```
python3 -m venv your-env
```

for environment activation:

```
source your-env/bin/activate
```